# Moto G on cyanogenmod 13 has a black screen but phone seems to be running in background

Tags: cyanogenmod, adb, motorola-moto-g

I have the CM13 installed on my Moto G (Falcon).

Last week, I left the phone on charge longer than usual and I came back to find dark screen. I have tried restarting it and I can feel the phone vibrate when it powers back on, however I cannot see anything on the screen. When the phone is "on" or I press the lock button, it goes from the shade of black to a shade of gray.

I have tried connecting it to the adb but `adb shell` doesn't recognise any device.

The phone must be working though as the alarm goes off every morning.

I have tried looking at several solutions on the web with little success.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issues too and your best bet is to reset the phone via a custom recovery(assuming you have one installed) since you flashed cm13.

Comment: Thanks Bismeet. I would try to do that but i cannot see any options on screen to proceed.

Comment: Do you have a custom recovery installed?

Comment: I did install it, yes.

Comment: Then you should be able to boot into recovery from bootloader mode.

Comment: That's the problem, I think. I don't see anything on screen. Not even when the phone is restarting. Just a dark screen.  But if it has power, i can hear the alarm at their right times.

Comment: Can u boot into bootloader?

Comment: I have tried but have been unable to do so. I'll give it a go again tonight. Will upvote if it works, have to rush off to work now